# javascript generate repeated images in meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, reactjs

Can anyone help I am trying to have an image that repeats according to how many portions there are. I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined.

I am using meteor and react

```
genPrtnImg: function () {
 var pNum = FoodItemsC.find(this.props.foodItem.portionNo);
 for (i = 0; i < pNum; i++)
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = "http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/carrot-icon-14142.png";
return img;
},
```

the function is called in the render below:

```
render() {
    return (
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowSpan="3"><img className="itemSmlPic" src="http://bed56888308e93972c04-0dfc23b7b97881dee012a129d9518bae.r34.cf1.rackcdn.com/sites/default/files/veggie-heart.jpg"></img></td>
          <td><h1>{this.props.foodItem.foodName}</h1></td>
          <td rowSpan="3"><img className="itemSmlPic" src="http://thesocialmediamonthly.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/photo.png"></img></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{this.props.foodItem.foodDesc}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{this.genPrtnImg()}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    );
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What;s the value of `pNum`?

Comment: @u_mulder between 1-10

Comment: Any chance the code is running on the server instead of just the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not enclosing your entire for loop inside curly brackets so your for loop is actually only iterating over this line `var img = document.createElement('img');`. Because of this and the fact that your var is declared inside the for loop i.e. doesn't exist outwith that one line of code when you hit the next line and do `img.src =` you get your error because img doesn't actually exist here. Fix is to wrap in brackets

```
for (i = 0; i < pNum; i++) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = "http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/carrot-icon-14142.png";
}
```

B) This still wont work because when you return `img` you are also returning outside the scope of the for loop hence the img does not exist. You could move it inside the for loop but this would mean it would only ever execute the loop once and as soon as it hits the return line it will return a singular img value

EDIT:

A fix for this would possibly be to push these values to an array and return that (wrapped in an element so react doesn't have a wipe out):

```
genPrtnImg: function () {
  var pNum = FoodItemsC.find(this.props.foodItem.portionNo);
  var i=0;
  var x = [];
  for (i = 0; i < pNum; i++){
    x.push(<img src='http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/carrot-icon-14142.png' />);
  }
  return <div>{x}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Philip, this has got things moving a bit. This code definitely works for repeating things. However, I am having a problem as react is not liking the object in its rendering: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLImageElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.
You have mentioned that you do not use react, but any insight you may have will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try modifying the `imgs.push(img);` to use `imgs.push(img).outerHTML;`, it looks like React requires a string but we are sending the HTML element representing the image. Let me know if it works and Ill update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: No joy i'm afraid, still getting the same error message. It did slightly change, the page now partially renders, but nothing involving the file this code is from.

Comment: @GeorgeBatty Had a quick play on a React fiddle and got the above edit to the question working in the simplest form I could manage, couple of things I discovered :D React requires raw elements (I am not sure what else to call them) not HTML or strings. For the return value, arrays are fine but if it is an array must always be wrapped up in a surrounding outer element and as mentioned must be an array of raw elements. Hope that helps! You can test here - https://jsfiddle.net/pip87/69z2wepo/32249/

Comment: legend! it worked, seems like just adding the <div> tags inside the function on the return did the trick! :) if you update the answer i'll accept it. Thanks so much for your help dude!

Comment: Haha Not that good or I would have got it first time, anyway, enjoy and peace out!

Comment: Ahhh, the fabled 'getting the code right first time', surely only a myth! This is a really handy bit of code though, found another 2 uses for it already - thanks again!